# Default queue binding in RabbitAdmin

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Today, our application have a vhost, a ConnectionFactory and a RabbitAdmin followed by multiple queue and exchange declaration. Now we have a requirement where I need a new vhost, hence a ConnectionFactory & RabbitAdmin

After creating the new vhost, the problem I'm facing is, all existing queue and exchange is getting created in both vhost. To address this issue, I used `declare-by="RabbitAdminName"` property which I can use in both queue and exchange level. As my application is having multiple queue and exchange hence I prefer not to disturb all existing config by adding declare-by in each queue definition.

Is there a way(global config to change the default behavior) to tell rabbit that only the intended new queue will go to the new vhost/ConnectoinFactory/RabbitAdmin and not the already existing queue. Any help is highly appreciable(I'm looking for the xml way of deceleration)

> By default, all queues, exchanges, and bindings are declared by all
>   RabbitAdmin instances (that have auto-startup="true") in the
>   application context.

Reference: [spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no global setting for this; you have to configure each queue etc and set the `declare-by` property to limit the declaration to an explicit admin.

So you would need to do this for your old queues to only declare those queues on the old vhost.

We could add a flag to the admin to exclude any beans that do not explicitly request declaration by this admin.

Please [open a new feature issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues).

Comment: Thanks @gary. Opened a ticket: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1074

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

```
@Bean
public RabbitAdmin admin() {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(cf1());
    rabbitAdmin.afterPropertiesSet();
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin admin2() {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(cf2());
    rabbitAdmin.afterPropertiesSet();
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    Queue queue = new Queue("foo");
    queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin());
    return queue;
}

@Bean
public Exchange exchange() {
    DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange("bar");
    exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin());
    return exchange;
}

@Bean
public Binding binding() {
    Binding binding = new Binding("foo", DestinationType.QUEUE, exchange().getName(), "foo", null);
    binding.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin());
    return binding;
}
```

By: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#conditional-declaration